# QML Label max width & multiline

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a Label, but it should only be as long as the form. If the label is longer it should start on a new line.
How can I realize this? I am using QtQuick Controls 2.0

My current code for the Label:

```
Label {
    id: lblMsg
    width: ApplicationWindow.width - 10 // not working
    text: "ajksdlldjklasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
    x: 20
    y: 20
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`wrapMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop) property:

```
Label {
    id: lblMsg
    width: ApplicationWindow.width - 10
    text: "ajksdlldjklasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
    x: 20
    y: 20
    wrapMode: Label.WordWrap
}
```

I'd suggest using [Qt Quick Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html) to manage the layout of your application instead of sizing items manually.

Answer (score 7):

add this line:

```
 wrapMode: Text.Wrap
```